# Leitor de Captcha em Portugues - Google noCaptcha reCaptcha

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

Olá, estou implementando um captcha no meu sistema, procurando no google consegui tutoriais e consegui por o captcha do google que é bem massa e já vem com uma opção falada para responder o captcha só que é em Inglês. 
Já tentei pesquisar e não achei nada que me ajudasse.

Alguém sabe se tem como traduzir essa opção no captcha do google?

Answer (score 2):

Até o momento a opção não existe tradução do áudio do reCaptcha, apenas os textos são traduzidos. De acordo com o guia, existe o parâmetro GET `hl` para configuração do idioma.

Exemplo: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt-BR'></script>`.

Segundo a documentação esse parâmetro:

> Força o widget a **renderizar** em um idioma especifico.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_param, tradução nossa, grifo nosso.

Answer (score -1):

Segundo a issues https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/106

use `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt'></script>`

sem o -BR, assim o áudio ficará em português, para mim funcionou.